# GitLab private maven repository not working in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: gitlab, spring-cloud-dataflow, maven-repository

I'm trying to register a task from my GitLab private maven repository...

I launch Spring Cloud DataFlow and Skipper with these properties:

```
maven.remote-repositories.gitlab.url: ${GITLAB_PACKAGE_REPOSIOTRY_URL}
maven.remote-repositories.gitlab.auth.username: ${GITLAB_PACKAGE_REPOSIOTRY_USERNAME}
maven.remote-repositories.gitlab.auth.password: ${GITLAB_PACKAGE_REPOSIOTRY_PASSWORD}
```

So I register the app as:

```
maven://com.xxx:dummy:0.0.1
```

When I trying to launch a task it can't be resolved saying:

```
dataflow-server_1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to resolve MavenResource: com.xxx:dummy:jar:0.0.1. Configured remote repositories: : [gitlab],[springRepo]

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.xxx:dummy:jar:0.0.1 from/to springRepo (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
```

It seems that SCDF try to download the maven package only from springRepo and not from gitlab.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using these properties:

```
maven:
  use-wagon: true
  remote-repositories:
    gitlab:
      url: ${GITLAB_PACKAGE_REPOSIOTRY_URL}
      wagon:
        http:
          all:
            use-preemptive: true
      auth:
        username: ${GITLAB_PACKAGE_REPOSIOTRY_USERNAME}
        password: ${GITLAB_PACKAGE_REPOSIOTRY_PASSWORD}
```

both for Spring Cloud Data Flow and Skipper Server